# Proper way to set php max_execution_time

Tags: php, config

i try to set my execution time in `php`, but seems like it doesn't work.

I have tried this.

```
<?php

function secondsToTime($s)
{
    $h = floor($s / 3600);
    $s -= $h * 3600;
    $m = floor($s / 60);
    $s -= $m * 60;
    return $h.':'.sprintf('%02d', $m).':'.sprintf('%02d', $s);
}
$a = microtime(true);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('max_execution_time', 3);
sleep(2);
echo 'oke';

sleep(3);
echo 'yes';
$b = microtime(true);

echo secondsToTime($b-$a);

?>
```

But when i try, it shows 11 seconds, instead of error or something.

why does my code doesn't error?? i set time to 6 secs. but my whole process is 11 secs?? 
Do i need to define it on my `php.ini` too?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's show me this Error

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 6 seconds exceeded
```

**You doesn't get this error because on your server  "Display Error" is not on.**

**Do i need to define it on my php.ini too ?**

No need to define it on php.ini too.you can set this dynamically like you already had.

Comment: but i still get the output from my last echo-ed...
is there something i missed?

Comment: RayanArief can you post full code ? because i didn't get why this happen

Comment: okeyes0:00:05 

"without any error",.. :D, do u have any idea?

Comment: no i didn't get but yes may be your sleep function not work or execution time out.....Sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 1):

`set_time_limit` sets the maximum execution time in seconds. If set to zero, no time limit is imposed

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

> By default, the maximum execution time for PHP scripts is set to 30
>   seconds. If a script runs for longer than 30 seconds, PHP stops the
>   script and reports an error. You can control the amount of time PHP
>   allows scripts to run by changing the max_execution_time directive in
>   your php.ini file.

Comment: why does my code doesn't error??

i set time to 6 secs. but my whole process is 11 secs??

Comment: By default, the maximum execution time for PHP scripts is set to 30 seconds. If a script runs for longer than 30 seconds, PHP stops the script and reports an error. You can control the amount of time PHP allows scripts to run by changing the max_execution_time directive in your php.ini file.